# Displaying Database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following.

controllers/customers.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 
 session_start(); //we need to call PHP's session object to access it through CI
 class customers extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct()
 {
     parent::__construct();
}

public function view($id) {

    $this->load->model('customers');
    $news = $this->customers->view_customer($id);
    $data['title'] = $news['title'];
    $data['body'] = $news['body'];
    $this->load->view('customers_customer_view', $data);

}

function index()
 {
  if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
 {
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
     $this->load->view('customers_view', $data);
   }
  else
  {
    //If no session, redirect to login page
    redirect('login', 'refresh');
   }


  }

 function logout()
 {
  $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
  session_destroy();
  redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
 }

 }

?>
```

models/customer.php

```
<?php
class customers_model extends CI_Model {


public function __construct()   {
   $this->load->database(); 
}

public function view_customer($id) {
  if($id != FALSE) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('id' => $id));
    return $query->row_array();
  }
  else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
}
?>
```

views/customers_customer_view.php

```
<?php print $title; ?>
<?php print $body; ?>
```

I am very new to code igniter, I have followed this tutorial from the web, No matter what i do i cannot get the database info to display when loading root/customers/view/1

All i get is a blank page. Even if i change the view to include a some static text it wont display, From this i believe it to be something wrong with loading the view, But all looks ok to me.

Please can somebody assist.

Comment: print that result somewhere
i mean controller or model.
Or try print_r($news);
Also remove session_start();

rename model name to customers_model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

```
$this->load->model('customers');
```

But model file is named: customer.php.
And class name is: customers_model.
Please check it again.

I will give you an example:

```
$this->load->model('customers');
```

Your model file have to be: customers.php.

And your class name have to be: class Customers {}

Comment: I change the model to "class customer_model extends ....." also i change the controller to "$this->load->model('customer');" And i still get a blank page

Comment: i now get it :), I thought that when naming a model that i had to complete it with _model. Its now working.